# NPM or Git caching files, can't build my project

Tags: reactjs, git, npm-start

I merged my branch with master, `git merge master`, and had a few conflicts. When I did this, my app was running and threw parser errors about the `<<<<<<<...` lines as expected.

I resolved the merges and now I'm getting the same error, but there is nothing in my code!

[image]

I can search the project for `<<<<` and find nothing. I've restarted my app `npm run start`, even switched branches, and it's stuck there. Made a new folder and recloned the project and that cleared it out. Any idea why/how this happened? How do I make sure this doesn't happen again.

Comment: I would request you to use Visual Studio Code instead of Sublime Text Editor. VSC by default has an option for 'accepting' incoming or current changes. This is a merge conflict. I would recommend you to go through  https://www.sublimerge.com/ as you are using Sublime Text Editor.

Comment: It seems that some merge is still missing / not confirmed. But you can try `npm cache clean --force` (if its a npm cache issue).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that a cache problem exists between webpack cache and resolving git conflicts.

the solution is:

- stop your app
- remove node_modules/.cache
- start your app

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that when you were trying to resolve the merge conflicts, pieces of your code were not marked as resolved.

A personal tip:
Using a GUI interface when resolving merge conflicts will help tremendously.
Applications like [Github Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) or using Github's own merge conflcit resolve will help better see your changes.

Comment: How do you mark it as resolved? I have conflicts all the time. I edit the file, accepting what I want, then `git add .` and `git commit` to finish the merge. Works like a charm. However, here the conflicts were stuck

Comment: You would also need to `git push` as well to push changes to the remote repository.

Comment: It doesn't have no sense. I mean, I know that if you don't resolve the conflicts... you still will have, conflicts. But that is obvious, OP is asking why is marking as not solved if he says that they are all solved